# React/Redux Handling Two-Way Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I'm struggling to properly organize my Redux Store and my React components to properly deal with two-way nested data.

Suppose I have a `post` model and a `user` model. Let's take an abstracted example:

```
const user = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "user 1",
    "posts": [...] // list of post objects
}

const post = {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "post 1",
    "user": user
}
```

The problem is that I cannot load this data like this because it will cause an infinite recursion error. I have to omit either the `posts` from the `user` or omit the `user` from the `posts`.

Here's what I ideally need:

I need to have a single `post` page that displays the post `user` with all his info (id, name) and the user's list of `posts` with the post info (id, title) in the same screen all at once.

I use `normalizr` to normalize the data.

How would I go about loading the data?

Answer (score 2):

As per Redux docs (https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) you should avoid nesting objects.

The solution here would be to treat the data like it is a database. That means that you should store ids instead of objects.

In your example:

```
const user = {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "user 1",
  "posts": ["1", "2", ...] // list of post objects IDs
}

const post = {
  "id": "1",
  "title": "post 1",
  "userId": "1"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how would `normalizr` know to do that? I need the full objects from my API first, with their relations, which I can't get because of the recursion problem.

Comment: Where does it throw recursion error? Maybe you need to fix the API, for example in .net core you have to add something like ...options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; Regarding normalizr, how did you configure it? It should detect nested objects and normalize it just like in the example thats mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Each `post` has a `user` and each `user` has a list of `post`s. The error happens when trying to serialize all of them into one big `JSON` response, to then send to `normalizr`. I know I'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure how to load all the posts and users that would come from a simple query like that. Any general ideas or pointers?

Comment: Where are you trying to serialize it? On backend or on frontend? Who is trying to return this response you are mentioning?

Comment: My backend is Python, using SQLALchemy models. I'm sending that info to React. To not waste any more time and keep it simple, what if I need a `post` page that shows in our example `user 1`, and a list of `user 1`'s posts, with each post's `title` all on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would only save `post_ids` in the user, and `user_id` in the post. `normalizer` schemas can be configured to deal with those relations.

Comment: Does that saving come before normalizing with `normalizr`? Or is it part of the normalizing process? Should I configure `post_ids` from my API? Because I know `normalizr` does it by default, but I first need to have loaded my full objects with their relations, which gives me the recursion problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the incentive of adding the `user` key in `post`? Having shared data within two related data structures is redundant. The only data you should have in `post` is the relevant data and the minimum amount of information you need to properly associate the `user` with his/her `post`s. I would imagine you would want to have the string name of the user in `post`, or an id number of the user inside each `post` object

```
const user = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "user 1",
    "posts": [...] // list of post objects
}

const post = {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "post 1",
    "user": "user 1"
}
```

EDIT:
From your comment, I would make an array of all `users`. But with a `post` key that is only the `ids` of posts that are associated with that user. And another array of only `posts`. As before, have an identifier to correlate the two. After that, parse your frontend on an as needed basis.

```
const users = [
  { name: 'andrew', id: 10, postIds: [1,3,23,30]},
  // ...more users
]

const posts = [
  { name: 'a post', id: 23, userId: 10 }
  { name: 'another post', id: 3, userId: 10 }
  { name: 'a third post', id: 2, userId: 3 }
  // ...more posts
]
```

Technically, `userId` is optional, but it can be a nice-to-have to be able to identify a user when inspecting individual posts

EDIT:
Wow, I just scrolled down and saw nordus has the exact same proposal, before me. While it's nice to see we're on the same page, make sure he/she gets credit if you like the idea ;).

Comment: That's the goal. That's what `normalizr` is for, however, the data from my API isn't normalized, it contains the full objects, where I have my recursion problem. My question was badly formulated, `normalizr` is not the problem. The problem is I need to get both objects in full from the API first

Comment: An api that returns data of this nature is a mistake. This is a backend problem. The database query's structure, if it's fetching everything in its entirety, makes it sound like you're not `SELECT`ing specific attributes. Fix your models to extract/send exactly what you need. It shouldn't be the frontend's responsibility to do so much parsing of this nature

Comment: I have control over my API. Given the models above, any quick guidelines on how I should load them? Each `post` has a `user` and each `user` has a list of `posts`. I need to fetch all that data somehow, to send it to `normalizr` to have all my entities and references in place.

Comment: Modify `post`. I don't know what your api framework/library is, but ultimately you need to remove the data structure containing all users inside each `post` and add some type of identifier that can logically point to a user. So probably something like `{title: 'post 1', userId: '1'}`

Comment: That's fair, but what if I need that data? What if I need a post page that shows in our example `user 1`, and a list of `user 1`'s posts, with each `post`'s `title` all on the same page? I'm not sure where to remove, or how to load that because its all necessary no?